# Consequence of negative variance-covaraince matrix on loss

Tags: correlation, variance

I need some help in understanding the impact of a negative varaince-covaraince matrix to loss. For example, I have three loss data sets A,B and C. each has mean and variance. When calculating 3x3 variance-covarance matrix, the determinant is negative.

My ultimate goal is to simulate aggregate loss (A+B+C) through assuming distribution etc.

I wonder what the consequences of having negative varaince-covaraince matrix to the aggregate loss? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If the determinant of the covariance matrix is negative, then you are calculating the covariance matrix wrong.  Covariance matrices are always positive semi-definite.  The mean of and variance of the "total loss" $(A+B+C)$ are given by

\begin{align}
\text{Mean}(A+B+C)&=\text{Mean}(A)+\text{Mean}(B)+\text{Mean}(C)\\
\text{Var}(A+B+C)&=\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \text{Cov}(A,B,C)_{i,j}
\end{align}